# How to check if location in 2d list exists

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, tuples

I am currently building a function that checks if a location on a board exists and returns boolean values. The location is given as a tuple and the board aka puzzle is given as a 2d list.

For example:

> is_valid_location((1,1),   [[None]]) → False
>
> is_valid_location((1,1),   [[1,2],[2,1]]) → True (because 2x2  puzzle  has a   row 1   and col 1)
>
> is_valid_location((1,2),   [[1,2],[2,1]]) → False

My current code is attempting to assign index 0 of the tuple as x and index 1 of the tuple as y. Then I'm trying to return the boolean value.

```
def is_valid_location(loc,puzzle):
    location=tuple(loc)
    x=location[0]
    y=location[1]
    return x in range(len(puzzle[0])) and y in range(len(puzzle))
```

The function is not working because I am getting indentation errors, but to my knowledge I've indented correctly. Is there a simpler way to do this without calling any built in functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No indentation errors could be found. If you get this error it's mostly caused when you copy paste code in with a mix of tabs and spaces. Remove all spacing and then tab them out again.

Your function could also be simplified to

```
def is_valid_location(loc, puzzle):
    x, y = loc
    return 0 <= x < len(puzzle[0]) and 0 <= y < len(puzzle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works exactly the way you describe when I copy it into my editor, so I would recommend exploring the indentation error further. You might be mixing tabs and spaces; this can be resolved by changing the settings of your text editor such that it always replaces tabs with 4 spaces. Unfortunately it is difficult to help you further without seeing the traceback of the error.

Comment: Here is the error: >File "kgreenw_222_p4.py", line 14
    def get_value_at_location(puzzle,loc):
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block